# Scanner Object - Splitting String

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to write a string input to a text file using the Scanner object.

The string input is a film name. If the file name has two words, though, the scanner object only takes the first word.

I need it to take both words. Here is my code:-

```
Scanner new_dvd_info = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter name of new film");`          
String film_name = new_dvd_info.next();
```

Can anybody shed any light please?

Comment: `Scanner#next()` only returns what comes *before* space. You should use `Scanner#nextLine` instead which reads the whole line, then use `String#split`.

Answer (score 5):

Replace `new_dvd_info.next()` with `new_dvd_info.nextLine()` to grab the entire line.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation of `Scanner.next()` method says

```
Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.
A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches
the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input 
to scan, even if a previous invocation of {@link #hasNext} returned 
<code>true</code>.
```

So it would just pick up until it finds " " as delimiter in your case. You could use next line method on scanner to get whole string `new_dvd_info.nextLine()` alternatively you could just loop over like:

```
 while(scanner.hasNext) {
      //append to string using scanner.next();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using `new_dvd_info.next()` which returns the first complete token. If any delimiter such as `space` is encountered it considers the next word as a separate token.

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String s=sc.next();
System.out.println(s);
```

In the above code if you give the name of the movie as `Age of Ultron` it will return you just the token`Age` as there is a delimiter after the token age.

In case you want the complete `String` separated by delimiter you should use

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String s=sc.nextLine();
System.out.println(s);
```

This will give you the desired output i.e. `Age of Ultron`